# Changing value of cell in Excel via apache-poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm trying to change value of cell in .xls document.

In .xls file i have got only 1 cell - A1 with `abc` value inside.

My code:

```
        File fo = new File("D:\\TMP\\Zeszyt1.xls");
        HSSFWorkbook a = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(fo));
        HSSFSheet my_sheet = a.getSheetAt(0);
        HSSFRow my_row = my_sheet.getRow(0);

        HSSFCell myCell;
        myCell = my_row.getCell(0);
        myCell.setCellValue("NEW VALUE");
```

How to commit this changes? When i open .xls file i still have got `abc` value inside A1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to [`write`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write%28java.io.OutputStream%29) to the file.

```
FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("abc.xls"));
workbook.write(outputStream);
outputStream.close();//Close in finally if possible
```