# How to replace a cell value - Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to **replace a cell value using existing cell value** from other sheets(in the same workbook)

My code:

```
public static void update_sheet(XSSFWorkbook w)
   {
    XSSFSheet sheet,sheet_overview;
    sheet_overview = w.getSheetAt(0);
    int lastRowNum,latest_partition_date;
    latest_partition_date = 3;
    XSSFRow row_old, row_new;
    XSSFCell cell_old, cell_new;


    for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
        {
            sheet = w.getSheetAt(i);

            lastRowNum = sheet.getLastRowNum();

            row_old = sheet.getRow(lastRowNum);
            cell_old = row_old.getCell(0); //getting cell value from a sheet 

            row_new = sheet_overview.getRow(latest_partition_date);
            cell_new = row_new.getCell(5);
            ***cell_new.setCellValue(cell_old)***;//trying to overwrite cellvalue

            latest_partition_date++;
        }

    }
```

The 'type' values I am trying to copy

```
7/10/2017
7/11/2017
7/12/2017
7/13/2017
2017-07-14
2017-07-15
```

Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method setCellValue(boolean) in the type XSSFCell is not applicable for the arguments (XSSFCell)

at Sample2.update_overview_sheet(Sample2.java:78)
at Sample2.main(Sample2.java:26)
```

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: You can look at post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574490/changing-value-of-cell-in-excel-via-apache-poi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `getCell()` returns a value of type Cell. You're not actually retrieving the value of that cell, but the cell object itself. In order to set the value with `setCellValue` you need to provide it a value, something that's a date, boolean, string, richtextstring, etc., one of the methods that's [listed here](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) in the apache POI documentation for Cell.

Comment: Hey Tim, I tried this **s = row_old.getCell(0).toString();             
                   cell_new = sheet_overview.getRow(2).getCell(5);
    cell_new.setCellValue(s);
    latest_partition_date++;**                                                      I get NullPointerException

Comment: That takes a cell object and converts it to string. You should be using the [getStringValue()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellValue.html#getStringValue()) method.

Comment: Thanks for the help Tim